# Avoid exposing LinkedIn API key in HTML

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I want my users to login using the *Sign In With LinkedIn* feature. The LinkedIn API docs provides the following example snippet for getting started:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY_HERE
    authorize: true
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Setup an event listener to make an API call once auth is complete
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    // Handle the successful return from the API call
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Handle an error response from the API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Use the API call wrapper to request the member's basic profile data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

</script>
```

How to I implement this without exposing YOUR_API_KEY_HERE to the public? There's a few npm packages out there that handle this kind of thing, but they are all old (I get nervous whenever a package hasn't been updated in at least a year).

My application uses node and express. Should I go with an old npm package or is there a better way to hide the api_key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ok and necessary to have YOUR_API_KEY_HERE in the javascript or website and it is necessary at times. They important piece is not to share your SECRET_KEY because you need both to do anything with the API. Be sure to always use HTTPS for all communications.

From the linkedin best practices for security application website: 
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/best-practices

API Key & Secret Key

When making calls to the LinkedIn APIs you use two pieces of identifiable information: the API Key (sometimes called the Consumer Key) and the Secret Key (or Consumer Secret).

The API Key is a public identifier of your application and the Secret Key is confidential and should only be used to authenticate your application on the LinkedIn APIs.

Since both the API Key and Secret Key are needed together to confirm your application’s identity, it is critical that you never expose your Secret Key.  Here are some suggestions for proper Secret Key storage:

When creating a native mobile application, do not store it locally on a mobile device.

Do not expose in any client side code files like JavaScript or HTML files.

Do not store it in files on a web server that can be viewed externally e.g.: configuration files, include files, etc.

Do not store it in log files or error messages.

Do not email it or post it on a message board or other public forum.

Remember that when exchanging an OAuth 2.0 authorization code for an access token, the Secret Key is passed as part of the request. Do not expose this request publicly!